# Removing non-printable and/or unicode chararacters from large XML-file

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, sax

I have a method which receives a File object, containing XML-data. Files can be over 50 MB. Is there a convenient way to remove control chars and/or non-printable chars from it.

For smaller files I read the File contents to String and use replaceAll("\p{Cntrl}", "").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1). Use notepad++ or ms word and use find/replace 
2) Write java program using bufferedStream find and replace the stringtokens

Comment: Manual editing is a no no, but thanks for pointing the rigt direction.